# Regular Expresion find space and bracket from fileName without extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, regex, regexp-replace

I am using javascript This is my string

```
let filename1 = "excluder version(1).pdf"
```

note : extension will be dynamic such jpg or png

I want to replace string with result
how to do this if using regex?

result or expected :

```
filename = "excluder-version-1.pdf"
```

Comment: Example: `filename1.replace(/\s+/, '-').replace(/\((\d+)\)/, '-$1')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex **[^a-z0-9]+** , which will replace all the element other than number and small alphabet with space.
Also you can get the extension using substring and later on add it to the final result.

```js
let filename1 = "excluder version(1).pdf"
var extension = filename1.substring(filename1.indexOf('.')+1)
var filename = filename1.substring(0,filename1.indexOf('.'))
filename=filename.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g," ").trim().split(" ").join("-")+"."+extension;

console.log(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it!

```js
let filename1 = "excluder version(1).pdf"
let re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)\((\d+)\)\.(pdf|jpg|png)/;


const matches = filename1.match(re).slice(1);
const newstr = matches.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  if (index === matches.length - 1) {
    return acc + '.' + curr;
  }
  return acc + '-' + curr;
});

console.log(newstr);
```